# Is there a way to share config data among angular components?

Tags: angularjs

I have about 10 components, and they all have the same bindings, and mostly the same controllers.  The only thing that is different among each component is the templateUrl, and maybe a small addition to the controller.

Since Angular components take a config object rather than a factory function, does that mean I just have to use a bunch of copy/paste among my 10 components?

I know I could share config if I change them to directives, but I was hoping to keep these as (future-friendly) components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use common config object and extend it with custom properties if it needs to:

```javascript
var getConfig = function() {
  return {
    controller: function() { console.log('default controller'); },
    templateUrl: 'default.html',
    bindings: { }
  }
}

// default component
app.component('one', getConfig())

// different templateUrl
app.component('two', angular.extend(getConfig(), {
  templateUrl: 'another.html'
}))

// different controller
app.component('three', angular.extend(getConfig(), {
  controller: function() { console.log('another controller'); }
}))

// ... and even extend controller itself
app.component('four', angular.extend(getConfig(), {
  controller: function() {
    // inherit default controller
    getConfig().controller.call(this)

    // and add custom functionality
    this.newMethod = function() {}
  }
}))
```

Comment: If I did that, would I be able to use dependency injection with the original/base controller?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed examples.  In example 4, the line `config.controller.call(this)` gives me infinite recursion.  I suppose it needs a different name in the base config(?)  But then that would break examples 1 & 2...